# Event not fired after BitmapImage finishes loading file on hard drive

Tags: c#, wpf, events, bitmap

I am loading an image to be shown on the screen and edited by the user, but I've run into a bit of a problem.

`BitmapImage` contains an event `DownloadCompleted` so I tried it, and it never gets fired. I suspect this is because the event [only fires if the file is on the internet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadcompleted.aspx):

> This event may not be raised for all types of bitmap content.

I am rendering the bitmap to a `RenderTargetBitmap` afterwards, so I can't just set the `Image.Source` like I would normally.

Is there any way to execute code only after the bitmap is finished loading (from the hard drive)?

EDIT:

I've just tested it a bit and found that the `BitmapImage` doesn't even start downloading the image until after my initialization method ends.

EDIT:

I've got it working by using the `Window.Activated` event, but I'm still open to better methods as this method is not such a good one.

Comment: This is purely conjecture, but have you tried converting the local file path to a `file://c/...` URI, as opposed to a `c:\...` path?

Comment: @ChrisShain I just tried it, and it loads the image, but it still doesn't raise an event.

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if it [`IsDownloading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.isdownloading.aspx), if that is false it is loaded, otherwise wait for the event.

Comment: I tried that as well, but the problem is that I don't want to be checking it every update.

Comment: It would be a good backup, but I'd just like to make sure there's no better way of doing it first